# Command: heroku Login is generatiing errors

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, node-modules

**I find it difficult to understand why i keep on getting this error when i do heroku login.**

$ heroku login

TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at Object. (C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/client/node_modules/chalk/index.js:72:75)
    at Object. (C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/client/node_modules/@heroku-cli/color/lib/color.js:1:17925)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

I uninstalled Heroku via Start - Add/Remove programs

```
>npm install chalk
>npm install ansi-styles
>npm install heroku
```

And that somehow fixed it.